# serilog push property using multiple times

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

I have a serilog middleware class implemented as per this blog post https://blog.datalust.co/smart-logging-middleware-for-asp-net-core/

if i want to use LogContext.PushProperty several time to push various pieces of information in my logging do i just need to put the following code inside my Invoke method:

```
LogContext.PushProperty("Address", httpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress);
LogContext.PushProperty("Username", httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? httpContext.User.Identity.Name : null);
```

the documentation for LogContext.PushProperty shows only adding one property and says to use a using block or do i need to do something like:

```
using (LogContext.PushProperty("Address", 
httpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress))
        using (LogContext.PushProperty("Username", httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? httpContext.User.Identity.Name : null))
    {  //rest of invoke method here }
```

Comment: your using syntax is correct as it is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an example https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment

```
log.Information("No contextual properties");

using (LogContext.PushProperty("A", 1))
{
    log.Information("Carries property A = 1");

    using (LogContext.PushProperty("A", 2))
    using (LogContext.PushProperty("B", 1))
    {
        log.Information("Carries A = 2 and B = 1");
    }

    log.Information("Carries property A = 1, again");
}
```

Just use multiplay using

```
    using (LogContext.PushProperty("A", 2))
    using (LogContext.PushProperty("B", 1)) 
    { ... }
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use the Push method for LogContext:

```
ILogEventEnricher[] enrichers = 
{
    new PropertyEnricher("Address", httpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress),
    new PropertyEnricher("Username", httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? httpContext.User.Identity.Name : null),
};

using (LogContext.Push(enrichers))
{
    // your code...
}
```